# Is it true that AES initialization constants, which are supposed to be random numbers, were in fact chosen by the NSA?

Tags: aes, nsa

Is it true that AES initialization constants, which are supposed to be random numbers, were in fact chosen by the NSA?

I mean, it's said it was done before algorithm standardization when it was still called *Rijndael*.

Comment: Can you reference a source for this claim?

Comment: So, the supposed story here is that the NSA went up to two Belgian guys and told them to use specific number in their design of a blockcipher, and the Belgians didn't say "Get lost!"?

Comment: Tell us why you think so.

Answer (score 4):

The conspiracy theory in the question is nonsense: none of the constants in [Rijndael](https://csrc.nist.gov/csrc/media/projects/cryptographic-standards-and-guidelines/documents/aes-development/rijndael-ammended.pdf) are supposed to be random (nor are they *initialization* constants). They all have a precise justification, making them as [nothing-up-my-sleeves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nothing-up-my-sleeve_number) as can be.

Note: and any of the three parametrizations of AES yields precisely the corresponding Rinjdael.